# Android retain callback state after configuration change

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I understand pretty well about Android lifecycle. I post here because I've observed one weird behavior, anyway this is my own thought.

My case is like this: One activity will use a simple layout with just a single `EditText`. In the activity `onCreate` method, i set some default text to the `EditText` and in later part of the method, assign a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` so whenever user types in anything, i can response in my own way.

Everything is alright until I rotate the screen. The `TextWatcher` callback starts to react against the code that initialize the `EditText`.

According to the normal code flow, the `TextWatcher` is assigned later after initializing text value of the `EditText`. so it's not supposed to fire because of the text assignment in the `onCreate` method.

Could anyone here explain this?

Answer (score 8):

Here is why you see this behavior:

1. When 'onCreate' method is called first time, it has no saved state. Which means `Bundle` `savedInstanceState` parameter is null.
2. When configuration changed, Android paths non-null value in `savedInstanceState` parameter.
3. After configuration is changed, and `onCreate` returns, Android calls `onRestoreInstateState`.
4. By default, all views that have `id` are trying to restore their state, `EditText` restores its state too (actually, that `TextView` who restores most of it).
5. At some place during state restoration (but after `onCreate` method is completed) your `EditText` control calls `setText` on himself in order to restore text that it had just before configuration changed.
6. Your *new* `TextWatcher` that you added in `onCreate` method is notified about this change.

---

Just to make this clear, your *old* TextWatcher, that you added on first call to `onCreate`, is not preserved! Its *new* TextWatcher, that was added on last call to `onCreate`, which receives the text change notification.

You can examine [TextView.onRestoreInstanceState](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/widget/TextView.java&l=2478) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you rotate the device the onCreate method of activity called again.if you want to prevent to call onCreate when rotating the device do the following code in the Manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

and in your activity

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{       
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);    

    if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {

    }      
    else if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {

    }  
}
```

Comment: with the android:ConfigChanges is just enough, you only need the code on you activity if you want to do something specific