# Callback after orientation change becomes null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have have a `FragmentActivity` with two tabs which are `ListFragment`s. Each `ListFragment` has a callback.

An example of a callback

The callback is associated inside of the *onAttach(...)* method

```
OnStatusUpdateListener mStatusUpdateCallback;

public interface OnStatusUpdateListener {
    public void onStatusUpdate();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach");
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mStatusUpdateCallback = (OnStatusUpdateListener)activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnStatusUpdateListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Later on, I communicate with the `FragmentActivity` by this callback which works fine normally.

Within the `ListFragment`, I have an `ImageButton` that will call a `DialogFragment` which also has a callback. This callback is implemented in my `ListFragment` and is what triggers the callback that is *null*

```
public void onStatusOption() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStatusOption");

    // Update stuff

    // Here is where mStatusUpdateCallback is null after rotate
    mStatusUpdateCallback.onStatusUpdate();
}
```

The problem is that if I ever rotate the phone while the application is running, **mStatusUpdateCallback** becomes *null*. This of course means I cannot execute the callback. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**What I've tried**

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029070/935779 it appears that a new reference to `OnStatusUpdateListener` may have been created so I cannot reference the old, but doesn't offer a solution.

I've also tried retaining the state as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787393/935779, but I can't save a reference to a callback as far as I can tell.

I also would really rather not do the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` method since that just seems like a hack and my layout changes in landscape.

**Stacktrace**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.blug.blah.Fragment.StatusFragment.onStatusOption(StatusFragment.java:197)
    at com.blug.blah.MyActivity.onStatusOption(MyActivity.java:243)
    at com.blug.blah.Dialog.StatusOptionDialog$1$1.onClick(StatusOptionDialog.java:108)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: initialize `callbacks` in `onConfigurationChange` method.

Comment: Its really hard to tell what is going on from the code  you posted. In theory that shouldn't happen. I have similar setups and I have not seen nullpointers. Can you post the logcat?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem See the code first :)

Comment: @Marco I've added a spot where I call it from as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: hmmm its still hard to tell whats going on. As an alternative you can use the LocalBroadcastManager that comes with the support library to pass data/messages(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager). Or you can also use an EventBus library such as Otto or EventBus by GreenDroid.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem If I handle `onConfigurationChange` and initialize the callbacks there too, it solves this problem. If you will put your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. (Creates a new problem, but you solved my issue in this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuration of the `Activity` being destroy and recreates.

When `Configuration` of the phone is changed the method `onConfigurationChange` called.

So you can initialize your `Callbacks` in `onConfigurationChange`

Answer (score 1):

First you can put this code into manifest  tag and force activity to save your callback `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
and Second you can use onConfigurationChange method to initialize your callback

Answer (score 0):

By default when your application changes orientation that whole activity is destroied and created. Because of this(and without more of your code posted) it can be assumed that your references are going null as the activity is destroyed and need to be reset when the activity is recreated.

Alternatively you can specify in your manifest that your activity handle orientation changes and then the activity will not be destroyed when orientation changes.

Comment: Thank you for your time with this. I did mention those things, but I guess I'm stuck on how to properly reinstate the references after orientation change.

Comment: How are you instantiating your views? Code or xml.

Comment: The layout itself is XML, but I inflate it in onCreateView